# Remove Facebook page likes automatically with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

As detailed in the my [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17574/facebook-page-receiving-improbable-amount-of-likes-from-unknown-users) on IT Security Stack Exchange, I am the administrator for a page with a many recent unknown (an undesired) likes.

It was suggested to me to learn the Facebook API and write an algorithm to remove likes automatically, based on thresholds (ex.: remove a like if the user has a suspicious amount recent likes).

I'm aware of the many other posts discussing issues with retrieving the like count for a Facebook page, but was unable to find any posts discussing *removing* likes as the page admin.

Is this possible to achieve? If so, how would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into using the block method.

```
PAGE_ID/blocked?uid=USER_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_BLOCK
```

This should do the same as removing the like. I am not sure whether unblocking the user resets the like or not (works on Twitter) so you can look into that as well with a `HTTP DELETE` on the same call.

As far as I know there is no way to explicitly remove a like from a page.

For more information see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#blocked

Comment: phwd, I think tha "blocked" users appears to mean a user is blocked from posting content. There are also "banned" users (a user is prevented from re-liking or otherwise interacting with the page). Therefore, I don't think it would reset the like...

Comment: @Natan Yip you are right it was an assumption on my part. Thanks for the validation