# How to reduce the number of likes for my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to reduce likes of my page. For eg, my page is liked by 700 people and I want reduce the likes to 500 ie not more than 500 people can like my page.

How can I do this using graph API.

Is there any way to delete the likes. I can delete the likes of a post by issuing a `HTTP DELETE to postID/likes` what about the page?

Comment: What have you tried, and what sort of answers did you get when you researched this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wanting to delete likes? Also, do you mean delete the likes that users have generated or likes that have been done on-behalf of the page?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I want to remove the likes of my fan page. @Lix I just want to reduce the likes of my Facebook fan page.

Comment: @admdrew There is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659019/remove-facebook-page-likes-automatically-with-facebook-api but there is no accepted answer.

Comment: you can't do that.... like and unlike can be done by the user himself or on behalf of the user (with the user's permission). You cannot reduce/increase the number of likes even if it is your own page... Imagine if we had that privilege everybody would have millions of likes for his own page... think before you post.

Comment: @iphondroid - Please make sure that you understand the question before answering. I know like and unlike can be done only by users. My question is can we achieve it using Facebook graph API or FQL. Any how I got the answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy. Yes you cannot control your likes but you can remove your page fans. 
You need to go to you page message. www.facebook.com/YourPage/messages there you'll see a link to 'see likes' click on it and choose the person you want to remove as a fan. see demo here https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYO5Q.jpg

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot make a user unlike your page.

The most reliable way to reduce likes is probably going to be posting offensive stuff.